# GridSearchCV custom y_train and y_test on each split

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, gridsearchcv

I am working with time-series data. Each row represents a customer and `y` is sale. So at time `T` user might not have a sale, but at `T+1` sale happened. So that row was a negative class on all previous folds, becomes a positive class on future folds.

I have a `List[(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)]`, is there a way to inject this list into the GridSearchCV?